# rename with filebeat processors from message body

Tags: filebeat

How to rename some fields ( for example -**\"s\":\"I\"**  and be **"severity":"INFO"**  on the **"message"**  from below output log : ?

```
   "agent" : {
    "ephemeral_id" : "28bb712f-0ec7-4e54-9ba5-c9533a7d4c9e",
    "id" : "86a3e0d9-dcd4-4424-820e-d856d1d93367",
    "name" : "ecs-basic",
    "type" : "filebeat",
    "version" : "7.10.2",
    "hostname" : "ecs-basic"
  },
  "message" : "{\"t\":{\"$date\":\"2023-07-10T03:17:02.015+00:00\"},\"s\":\"I\",  \"c\":\"CONTROL\",  \"id\":23403,   \"ctx\":\"SignalHandler\",\"msg\":\"Build Info\",\"attr\":{\"buildInfo\":{\"version\":\"4.4.20\",\"gitVersion\":\"5b82316e5017ff76646fd12878079620f9ad4be7\",\"openSSLVersion\":\"OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013\",\"modules\":[],\"allocator\":\"tcmalloc\",\"environment\":{\"distmod\":\"rhel70\",\"distarch\":\"x86_64\",\"target_arch\":\"x86_64\"}}}}"
}
```

I have my filebeat config but is now applying:

```
processors:
  - rename:
      fields:
        - from: "s"
          to : "severity"
      ignore_missing: false
      fail_on_errors: true
```